# Calculating polygon areas in QGIS generates NULL results

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm having a problem using QGIS and can't find a solution ... I searched this site and found a similar question ([QGIS $area field calculator always produces NULL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164582/qgis-area-field-calculator-always) -produces-null), but I couldn't solve my problems with the answers there ...

I have a file and every time I try to calculate the area of ​​the polygons, a lot of them returns as `NULL`. To calculate the areas I do the following:

- Right click on layer > Open Attribute Table
- Open Field Calculator
- I use the parameters below:

[image: Field Calculator parameters]

When I click OK to calculate, the table generates several regions with a NULL area value.

In the other publication (linked above) they recommended trying to use the "Lines to Polygons" tools to solve possible problems, or "Check Validity"

The "Lines to Polygons" tool I just can't use ... When I enter it, the "Input Layer" field appears empty and I can't select a layer to run it.

[image: Lines to Polygons parameters]

The "Check Validity" tool returns all areas as valid, and the 2 layers generated "error output" and "Invalid output" are empty.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Sample file (Shapefile I used to get to this errors):
https://we.tl/t-MuEKE7QF94

I'm using QGIS 3.16.3

Comment: I have tried your shp. After using the algorithm `Fix Geometries` that created a copy of your layer, the field calculator is working properly.